# Count current month from Database

Tags: php, mysql

i would like to count the date from the database where the month is now.
my code goes like

```
$sql="SELECT count(date) FROM tbl_upcoming where
date=MONTH(NOW())";
if ($results=mysqli_query($conn,$sql)){
    $datecount=mysqli_num_rows($results);
}
```

for example: '2017-3-20', '2017-3-4', '2017-1-3', it will return 2.

Comment: Is there a question here?

Comment: What is wrong with your query?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
SELECT date, count(1) FROM  tbl_upcoming where
MONTH(date)=MONTH(NOW()) and YEAR(date) = YEAR(NOW()) GROUP BY date
```

Comment: Resultset will be ambiguous, since there can be multiple `date` values in for each row.

Answer (score 0):

You were almost there:

```
SELECT count(*) FROM tbl_upcoming WHERE MONTH(the_date)=MONTH(NOW())";
```

The approach of `MONTH(NOW())` is good, this will return you the current month.
However you were comparing the current month with a whole date, which can't work. You also have to apply the `MONTH()` function to your date to compare months with months

Answer (score 0):

You should check like this,

month can be from past year or next year also,

```
select count(*) as cnt from tbl_upcoming 
where MONTH(date) = MONTH(CURRENT_DATE) and YEAR(date) = YEAR(CURRENT_DATE);
```

I hope this will help.

Answer (score 0):

You want to know how many rows are in the current month?

```
SELECT  COUNT(*)
    FROM  tbl_upcoming
    WHERE  `date` >= CURDATE() - INTERVAL DAY(CURDATE())-1 DAY;
```

Notes:

- In most situations, say simply `COUNT(*)`.
- `CURDATE()` is midnight this morning, hence easier to deal with for your query.
- `CURDATE() - INTERVAL DAY(CURDATE())-1 DAY` gives you the `DATE` of the first of this month.
- The formulation avoids all hiccups with various datatypes: `DATE`, `DATETIME`, `DATETIME(6)`, `TIMESTAMP`, etc.
- The next note handles leapdays, end of year, also.
- If you have dates reaching into future months, then

add

```
 AND `date` < CURDATE() - INTERVAL DAY(CURDATE())-1 DAY
                        + INTERVAL 1 MONTH;
```